# Loading many images simultaneously causing the browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, dom, promise

I am trying to load many images with javascript with the following code

```
let images = urls.map(loadImage);

function loadImage(url) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const img = new Image();
    img.loading = 'lazy';
    img.onload = () => {
        resolve(img);
    };

    img.onerror = () => {
        resolve(null);
    };

    img.src = url
    return promise;
   });
}
```

My problem is if I try to run this code many times (x1000 for example) it is causing the browser to freeze.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: it's probably the loop you're running that is causing the freeze - how many is "many times"?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I changed the code take a look at it

Comment: @Bravo I'm running it for 1000 times

Comment: Why do you use `fetch` instead of simply `img.src = url;`?

Answer (score 3):

#### JS is (predominantly) single-threaded

You may not be aware that, for the most part, all of your Javascript code runs in a single thread. This means that all the event handlers to respond to user input are competing with your JS code to be able to run on the one thread. So if your JS code takes a long time to execute, the browser tab will appear to lock up/freeze until it completes.

#### Why is loading 1000 images slow?

In order to load a single image in your `loadImage()` function, the browser has to do the following (amongst other things):

- allocate memory for a new `Image` object
- add the URL to the queue of network requests to make (which will also consume more memory)
- keep the `onload` function around to be able to call it when the response returns
- allocate memory for the image data returned
- take the bytes from the image data and pass it to `URL.createObjectUrl()` (which could take a while) - this also involves allocating memory for the resulting (large) string

Now imagine trying to do this 1000 times one after the other with no breaks in between. The amount of memory that needs to be allocated is extremely large and this memory pressure is likely to result in some forced garbage collection (GC) when the available memory is exceeded. Forced garbage collection in the middle of important code basically locks the browser until it completes.

All of the above puts an enormous strain on the main thread for that tab.

#### You should try to clean up object URLs when no longer needed

From the [MDN page on `createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Usage_notes):

> #### Memory management
>
> Each time you call `createObjectURL()`, a new object URL is created, even if you've already created one for the same object. Each of these must be released by calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` when you no longer need them.
>
> Browsers will release object URLs automatically when the document is unloaded; however, for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them, you should do so.

You are not explicitly unloading any of your object URLs, so all 1000 will be kept around in memory, adding to the memory pressure.

#### How can you fix this?

There are many strategies to avoid having to do this much work in such a short space of time. The basic idea is just to do less work at once, to allow the main thread an opportunity to do other things like respond to user input in between.

Doing less work might mean loading these images in "chunks" (small batches) and waiting until they are all loaded before fetching the next batch. Or it might mean implementing a "loading pool" type of approach, where you have a maximum number of images being loaded at once. As one finishes, you start loading the next one.

You should also think about how you can revoke these object URLs once you are done with them. Maybe add a `dispose()` function property to your returned promise that can call `urlCreator.revokeObjectURL()`.

#### Seriously rethink loading 1000 images

More than anything else, you need to take a step back and consider exactly *why* you need to load 1000 images at once in the first place. Depending on who your users are and what devices and connections they are on, that could be a very expensive waste of a person's data allowance, battery power (making network requests is one of the more taxing things on mobile device and laptop batteries), and available system memory.

You had better be *extremely certain* that all of your users will agree with you that loading those 1000 images is worth that large cost, even once you prevent it from locking up the main thread by doing it in batches, rather than all at once.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It's very helpful!!

Comment: If the images happen to be tiny *and* many of them are necessary, one might also consider using CSS sprites instead